# moment-timezone.js get utc offset for a specific date with timezone

Tags: momentjs

I have users entering a date and a time zone (e.g. "America/Los Angeles") for that date and I'd like to convert that to UTC but to do that I need the utc offset for the time on that date.

I can easily convert a date to the offset for the time zone if I already know the UTC date but I need the other way around...

The utc offset can change depending on the date due to daylight saving so I need a way to enter a date and a timezone  and get back the offset from UTC using that.

Knowing the most recent switch from PST to PDT On march 11 at 2AM I tried using

```
var tzOffset = moment.tz("3/11/2018 3:00 AM", "America/Los_Angeles").utcOffset();
document.write('utc offset is : ' + tzOffset + '<br/>') ;
```

but that gives 480 when the correct answer is 420

I can get the correct answer 420 if I use parseZone like so:

```
var tzOffset2 = moment.parseZone("3/11/2018 3:00 AM -07:00").utcOffset();
document.write('utc offset2 is : ' + tzOffset2 + '<br/>') ;
```

but that means I need to already know the -7 offset that I'm trying to find...

So how do I find the utcOffset for a specific date/time like  "3/11/2018 3:00 AM" and timezone like  "America/Los_Angeles"?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your input is not in a ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 format recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), so you have to specify the format as second parameter using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) (please note that, as [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) states: *The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the `moment` constructor, but uses the last argument as [a time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).*)

Your code could be like the following:

```js
var tzOffset = moment.tz("3/11/2018 3:00 AM", "D/M/YYYY h:mm A", "America/Los_Angeles").utcOffset();
document.write('utc offset is : ' + tzOffset + '<br/>') ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that . I was using https://momentjs.com/docs/ as a doc reference which has similar but it is buried deep whereas the ref you used is very lucid.